# Insignificent direct effect betwee IV and DV

Tags: regression, interaction

Can someone please explain why you can not hypothesize the insignificant direct effect between two variables? I know it to be statistically problematic, but don't understand why.

Comment: Also, when there is an insignificant direct effect - why moderators dont make sense?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking about why it is not OK to have an insignificant *main* effect for an independent variable in the presence of an interaction involving that variable. Well, it is OK. Statistical significance doesn't tell you anything about practical significance. Even if the main effects were zero it would still be OK to have meaningful interaction. It all depends on the context of the study/analysis/data.

As for statistical "significance", a main effect might have a p-value of 0.0499999 and someone could say "this is significant". On the other hand, the p values could be 0.0500001 and the same person would say "damn, this is insignificant". I would say that person is making a big mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not please let us know why so that it can be improved